# Automate writing for loop in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I keep writing for loops today. All of them have the format :

```
for(size_t szI = X; szI < Y; ++szI)
{
   //Something
}
```

And I know there are ways to record actions in vim. If X and Y can change, can I do something in vim to write a for loop once I supply X and Y somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) to store snippets, which you can then store a `for` snippet in.

In fact, it already comes with a lot of [predefined snippets](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/tree/master/snippets), a lot of which may prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is one example from [Vim wiki on abbreviations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations):

```
:abbreviate forl for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) {<esc>7hi
```

Not exactly what you wanted, but close to that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a macro:

```
let @f = "ifor(size_t szI = X; szI < Y; ++szI)^M{^M}^[O^T"
```

Note all `^X` characters are entered via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

You can then run this macro with `@f`.

Edit: Just saw the second part of your question (not sure if you edited it? Maybe I read wrong.) but if X and Y are going to change, I'd suggest a more featured solution such as snipMate.vim.

Answer (score 1):

The most evolved way is indeed to use an snippets engine.
snipMate has been evoked.

I'm maintaining [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) that is the root of the advanced snippets from [lh-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp#Templates).